# Is it OK to compose an aggregate with immutable data from another aggregate?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

**If an aggregate needs some read-only data that doesn't belong to itself to performs an operation, is there any negative consequence to let the repository query some data from another aggregate to create the aggregate?**

**In detail:**

I have a BC with two aggregates, say `A` and `B`. `B` needs a bit of data from `A` to perform some operation but won't modify it in any way. The data fits better on `A` since there are the rules to modify it.

Reading IDDD and PPP of DDD it seems that it is acceptable to pass a transient reference of an aggregate (or sub entity of it) to another one, or pass a read-only view as a value object to the other aggregate.

In my example, `B` doesn't need the whole `A` aggregate but only some specific data, so a value object seems like a good approach in this case. `A` could create the VO acting as a factory, the VO will conform to the UL and `B` doesn't need to be aware of `A` at all. A business use case in the application layer can reconstitute `A` and `B` from repositories, tell `A` to create the VO and performs operation on `B` passing VO.

Lets suppose now that reconstitution of `A` is expensive or there is another reason for what is not desirable to load the whole `A` to create the VO with just a bit of information (maybe the data is not from one instance of `A` but is aggregated from a list of them or whatever). Here a simple solution could be let the repository of `A` create the VO directly from the data store. I feel comfortable with this and seems it is a common pattern.

But now I'm thinking in a case when the operation on `B` is performed many times, or maybe is part of a bigger calculation on `B` that many other operations need. I could have a reference to the VO with the data needed (as a private, read-only property of `B` or somewhere in its graph) and let the repository of `B` take the data needed to create the VO and reconstitute `B` with it. Now `B` will always have the data *locally* to performs its operations. The data taken from `A` cannot be modified; saving `B` through its repository will just discard that data (maybe it could use it to detect a conflicting concurrent update), `A` and `B` will not be consistent at all times but that's OK, and reload `B` from repository will query the data again to update the view inside `B` in case of a conflict.

This approach seems OK to me since, as I understand, the domain model is unrelated to the data model, with the repository acting as a sort of ACL between the two. Also there is a single source of truth for the data inside `A` since the copy inside `B` is immutable and eventually consistent. The drawbacks I see are that repository will have more logic (but not business logic) and that it could be unclear where exactly the data is coming from since the dependency from `B` to `A` is now hidden inside infrastructural code.

So the questions are:

1. **Is this a not-so-good approach after all?**
2. **Is there another drawback I am not seeing?**
3. **Did you or someone do something like this so I can learn from that experience?**

---

I know the example is very poor since in DDD everything is about context. But this is a question I came up many times in different situations. I know as well that a valid concern is if aggregate boundaries are well defined, but let say they look good for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

> is it acceptable to let the repository query some data from another aggregate to create the aggregate?

Acceptable is kind of weakly defined.  A better question to ask might be "are there negative consequences?"

In this example, the usual consideration is whether or not the system becomes harder to change.  Take a look at Adam Ralph's talk on [service boundaries](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tVnIUZbsxWI) to get a sense for what happens when you don't control the coupling between components.

These days, if B needs a copy of A's data, then we usually introduce into our design of B a cache of A's data.  Store the copy of the data with B, and work out explicitly how and when updates to A are communicated to B.  The cache becomes part of B's data model.

See also Pat Helland's paper: [Data on the Outside versus Data on the Inside.](http://cidrdb.org/cidr2005/papers/P12.pdf).

Comment: You are right that "are there negative consequences" are better than "acceptable", I will edit the question. English is not my native language and sometimes a better expression just doesn't come to my mind.